# how long does buildozer generate apk take?

Tags: android, apk, kivy, buildozer

I am trying to build apk via buildozer using kivy, but not sure how long this process would be ...

Already waiting 50 mins, showing 
[image]

How long do I still need to wait? Or anything I missed leading this stuck state?

Comment: You might want to turn on debug mode (log_level = 2) in your buildozer.spec which will show you command output i.e. what it is doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depend on your internet connection, and your computing resources.
On my "not very powerful" laptop, the first build can take 10 minutes.
But this long build only happen the first time you have to build (or if you modify important informations on the buildozer.specs, or if if you use "buildozer clean"). Next builds take me less than a minute.
On a VM, it can take longer dues to lack of resources, but 45 min seem IMO like there was a problem.

Comment: I got openjdk, ANT, SDK, NDK, kivy, buildozer, anything else I should check? Any hint?

Comment: Cython version according to your specs and the most recent doc ? Even if I doubt that's it, looking at your blocking line. Try the hint on comment down your answer to enable more log, you will probably access to the downloads loading status, because it is after " Android NDK found at /home" that huges downloads begin